# Filtering an XML based on attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML file containing html text concerning one or several "zone"

this text is embeded in nodes named "myText".

```
<UrbanDoc myId="abc">
    <myText zone="general">
        <h1>1. General Text</h1>
        <div>blabla</div>
        <ul>
            <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
            <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
        </ul>
        <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="UG,1AU">
        <h1>2. Text related to 2 zones</h1>
        <myText zone="UG">
            <h2>2.1. Text only related to zone UG</h2>
            <div>blabla</div>
            <myText zone="UG,1AU">
                <h2>2.2. Text related to 2 zones</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
                    <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
                </ul>
            </myText>
            <div>more text blabla</div>
        </myText>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="1AU">
        <h1>3. Text related to 1AU</h1>
        <div>blabla</div>
        <ul>
            <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
            <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
        </ul>
        <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="N">
        <h1>4. Text concerning zone N</h1>
        <div>blabla</div>
        <ul>
            <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
            <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
        </ul>
        <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
</UrbanDoc>
```

I would like to filter the xml file in order to remove all branches (nodes and children nodes) that do not have zone containing "1AU".
Here is my xsl code :

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myText[not(descendant-or-self::myText[contains(@zone,'1AU')])]//*">
</xsl:template>
```

The result i get is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UrbanDoc myId="abc">
    <myText zone="general">
        
    </myText>
    <myText zone="UG,1AU">
        <h1>2. Text related to 2 zones</h1>
        <myText zone="UG">
            
            </myText>
            <myText zone="UG,1AU">
                <h2>2.2. Text related to 2 zones</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
                    <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
                </ul>
            </myText>
            <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="1AU">
        <h1>3. Text related to 1AU</h1>
        <div>blabla</div>
        <ul>
            <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
            <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
        </ul>
        <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="N">
        
    </myText>
</UrbanDoc>
```

And I would like to have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UrbanDoc myId="abc">
    
    <myText zone="UG,1AU">
        <h1>2. Text related to 2 zones</h1>
        
            <myText zone="UG,1AU">
                <h2>2.2. Text related to 2 zones</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
                    <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
                </ul>
            </myText>
            <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>
    <myText zone="1AU">
        <h1>3. Text related to 1AU</h1>
        <div>blabla</div>
        <ul>
            <li>bullet 1 blabla</li>
            <li>bullet 2 blabla</li>
        </ul>
        <div>more text blabla</div>
    </myText>

</UrbanDoc>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You will need to chain two transformations if you want to process the result of one transformation with another template. Inside of a single XSLT stylesheet you would need to use a variable to store the processing of one mode and then apply-templates to the variable in another mode. Keep in mind, that with an XSLT 1 processor you would need to use an extension function to convert the variable containing the result tree fragment of the first step to node-set processed by apply-templates.

Comment: You might be able to handle all in one XSLT. Can you post the sample XML in body of question? Also, comments in XSLT is not quite clear. Maybe just show current and desired output only.

Comment: Thank you martin, indeed, my problem seems to be related to xsl chaining, I will try to rephrase my question

Comment: Thank you parfait, here is a simplified XML, indeed, it may be feasible in one template, but i can't work out the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was //* in my template.

Replacing the second template with this code works

```
<xsl:template match="myText[not(descendant-or-self::myText[contains(@zone,'1AU')])]">
</xsl:template>
```